# I downloaded Python 3.12, but I'm unable to install CatBoost and Jieba using pip

Tags: python, pip, catboost, python-jieba

I've tried running the following commands:

```
pip install catboost
pip install jieba
```

However, both of these commands return an error. Can someone please assist me in resolving this installation issue with Python 3.12?

I also tried searching for relevant information on the official CatBoost documentation, but couldn't find a solution. Despite that, I attempted to download CatBoost from https://pypi.org/project/catboost/1.2.2/#modal-close and install it locally once more, but unfortunately, I'm still encountering the same error. Here is the error message I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import (
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\exceptions.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.pkg_resources import Distribution
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2164, in <module>
    register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
```

Is there anyone who has encountered a similar issue or has a solution for installing CatBoost with Python 3.12? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!